# Search on Products in Flask and Flask-SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, search, flask-sqlalchemy, fuzzy-search

I am currently building a backend for a mobile application with Flask and Flask-SQLAlchemy.

I am currently stuck in a function.

I have a Products table in Postgres database created with Flask-SQLAlchemy.
The products have the following fields :

- Brand
- Title
- Description
- Collection (Men/Women/Kids)
- Division (Clothing/Shoes/Bags & Accessories/...)
- Category (Tee-Shirts/Polos/Vests & Coats/Loafers/Slippers/ ...)
- Price
- Size id (Relationship to a table Size with records XS/S/...)

I would like to implement a search.
For example, when a user sends a request with men tee-shirts Zara, I would like to get the search over the DB performed with ORM query with Brand = Zara, Category = Tee-Shirts, Collection = Men

However, I am struggling with the approach as putting it in place myself would be difficult and I am afraid of the performance.
Specially for the cases where you have such search with 'Zara bags and Massimo Dutti shoes'

Do you have any suggestions ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Will you receive the search as seperate fields (brand=zara, collection=men) or do you want the user to be able to give you any string and you will have to figure out on the backend if zara is a brand or a collection?

Comment: I will have to figure out that Zara is brand as it is not with separated fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is probably a full text search engine which does the job for you. One possibility is to use [elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/de/elasticsearch). This is an additional programm which will run on your production server and you will need to feed it with the data from your original database. The implementation is far from trivial however there is [this](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-xvi-full-text-search)
great tutorial which provides a step by step solution for integrating elasticsearch (or any other fulltext search engine) with an flask application.

Using an existing search engine will cover all the complex search algorithms for you so that you do not have to implement it yourself

Comment: Is it safe to use it in prod from a performance pespective ?

Comment: Yes it is.  If you run into issues (unlikely from my point of view), you can make the search request async using background workers. (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tdIIJuPh3SI&t=7582s explained here at 1h30min). I would start with elasticsearch and look if you run into performance issues but I do not think this will happen